# Cannot run any stored procedure creation script using EF Core or LinqToDb EF Core Tools or ADO.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Steps to reproduce:

```cs
var s = @"USE `my_schema`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `my_schema`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
select 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
";

await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(s);
```

Exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()

- MySQL version: 8.0.21
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version: 5.0.8
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version: 5.0.0
- .NET version: 5.0.302

Comment: if you run that sql statement directly on your mysql db with the client tool does it work?

Comment: @rene Yes it does. (Via Workbench v8.0.25)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/delimiter/:

> This limitation does not exist in MySqlConnector, so using `DELIMITER` is unnecessary and it must be removed (to avoid sending invalid SQL to the server).
>
> To fix the problem, remove the `DELIMITER` declaration and any trailing instances of the delimiter:

```cs
var s = @"USE `my_schema`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
select 1;
END;
";

await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `MySqlScript` class, but Pomelo driver uses `MySqlConnector` library, which not included realisation in the library [tracking Issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/382)

But you can copy it's realisation from Oracle's source:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data/MySqlScript.cs

Usage is simple:

```cs
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var script = new MySqlScript(connection, scriptText);
    connection.Open();
    script.Execute();
}
```